# The MUI Select component not working and breaking the app on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

## **The problem is now solved**

I am building a modal with a form and want to use the MUI Select component, but as soon as I open the modal, the app breaks; if I remove the Select component, the app works just fine. I can't figure out the problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Error Message :

[image: Error Message]

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `MuiSelectIcon`.

## This is my current code:

### Booking.jsx

#### Select component

```
<Box>
                      <InputLabel id="gender">Gender</InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        id="gender-select"
                        required
                        native={false}
                        labelId="gender"
                        value={details?.gender ? details.gender : ""}
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="male">Male</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="female">Female</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="non-binary">Non-binary</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="Prefer not to specify">
                          Prefer not to specify
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Select>
                    </Box>
```

#### Imports:

```
//...
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Box from "@mui/system/Box";
```

Expected Output:

[image: A MUI Select Component]

Comment: Could you share the `handleChange` function and the structure of `details.gender`? If the Component is rendering fine first and then breaking once a selection is made, it implies that `handleChange` may be setting the value of `gender` to the option's object, rather than the option's value.

Comment: handleChange:

`const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked: checkboxValue } = e.target;

    setDetails({
      ...details,
      [name]: type === "checkbox" ? !checkboxValue : value,
    });`

details is an object which holds the data from the form. details.gender is a string value with options: 'Male', 'Female', 'Non-binary'.

The app breaks on first render, i.e. it breaks as soon as the modal is rendered.

Comment: @SuperEasyorigami what's the initial value of ```details``

Comment: it is `const [details, setDetails] = useState([{}]);` because if set otherwise, it causes error in firebase data formatting

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleChange` you are destructuring the name prop and using it as the key of the `details` object. But you haven't provided any `name` to `select` component and therefore the `details` state changes to something like this after the `handleChange` fires

```
{undefined: "female"}
```

I have forked a working sandbox reproducing your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-frost-ju9sfg?file=/demo.jsx)

Comment: What happens for me is that the app crashes and the select doesn't even render, it just crashes outright when the modal renders

Comment: on checking the error again I see it says `check the render method of **MuiSelectIcon**` are you using any custom icon in for select component or did you wrapped app.jsx with **<ThemeProvider>**

Comment: Yes, I have wrapped app.jsx with **<ThemeProvider>**. I am using the MUI Documenation website's theme in ThemeProvider

Comment: I think if you can share a codesandbox reproducing your error then someone might help you out, otherwise the Select components LGTM.

Comment: Even I think that the select component looks good, but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Now, I have discovered that the error is in the Theme.js file. Thanks for leading me to it